# Show deployment event

Tags: google-analytics

I'm deploying a new version of my website pages, which should hopefully have an impact on conversion rates. Thus, it'd be interesting that in the different GA views we could see a kind of special event noting that the deployment happened. So that marketing team members could understand at a glance where they should expect ratios to go up, and report proper numbers on what happened.

I am thinking about something like news in [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOG) (see those little "A", "B", "C" letters down on the axis of the graph?).

What's the best way to show and implement something like that with GA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Create new annotation" in Audience Overview:

[image]